# Dapper ORM vs Stored Procedure

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, dapper

I am working on a project where we are using DbContext but not EF for CRUD functionalities. We are using service layer for our business logic where stored procedures are written to fetch/send data to the database. I got to know about Dapper ORM which allows you to ease the interactions with the database. I was wondering if someone could give a brief up on the pros of using Dapper with MVC5 application instead of traditional Stored Procedures?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you comparing Stored Procedures with Dapper? If so, I do not see this as valid comparison. Both have their own benefits and drawbacks. Both are helpful in their own field of implementation.

Instead, if you are looking for calling Stored Procedure through Dapper, I suggest refer following posts; you can search for even more.

- [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962117/is-there-a-way-to-call-a-stored-procedure-with-dapper)
- [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21598437/execute-stored-procedure-w-parameters-in-dapper)

## My personal opinion:

I avoid to use Stored Procedures. I prefer to implement my Database code using ADO.NET or ORM depending on needs. This helps me centralize all my Database logic at one place. This also improves debugging and logging capabilities.

**Note:** That does not mean, I never use Stored Procedures or those should never be used. Those may be useful based on needs.

For implementing Data Access Layer using Dapper, please refer my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45029588/5779732).